# How do I create an object with Generics via reflection in c#

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

I need to find all the instances of objects which implement interface IFOO.
Then create the object and find some values of some properties of the object.

```
public interface IFoo
{

}
public class FooModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}


public class Foo<FooModel> : IFoo
{

}

public class Create{

    public void CreateInstances()
    {
        var itype = typeof(IFoo);
        var types = (from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                     from assemblyType in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
                     where itype.IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType)
                     select assemblyType).Where(m => m != itype);
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var genericArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
            var makeme = type.MakeGenericType(genericArgs);
            var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);

        }
    }
}
```

However when the newObject is created I get the following error:

Cannot create an instance of Foo`1[FooModel] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your problem description. On the one hand, you want to *find all instances*. On the other hand, you want to *create the object* (why? you already found your instances). Did you mean to say "find all classes implementing IFoo"?

Comment: this is a very good article on reflection: https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/4/Pages/1 Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is not what you may expect:

```
public class Foo<FooModel> : IFoo
{
}
```

`FooModel` is not your `FooModel` class here but a simple type parameter. You might want to define it like this:

```
public class Foo<T> : IFoo where T: FooModel
{
}
```

However, this will not solve you problem just makes it better understandable.

Your code just finds the generic type and tries to instantiate it like this:

```
new Foo<>();
```

But this will not work of course because your `genericArgs` contains a generic type definition (`T`) instead of a constructed type (`FooModel`). Do it like this to make it work:

```
var makeme = type.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(FooModel) });
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because when I create the object, I do not know the type FooModel. That is what I was expecting from the genericArgs.

Comment: This does not make sense. Your `Foo<TModel>` class is a generic one, you cannot instantiate it. You must fetch the actual `TModel` type from somewhere. If you do not know it before you load the assembly, then your `FooModel` should implement an `IModel` interface so you could find your `IModel` implementations and use them in `genericArgs`.